# Rails - ActiveAdmin - how to add a form in a panel into the index action related view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin

I need to show a form in the index action's related view, just above the list of records; my failing attempt (here below) puts my panel, and the included form, **into** the form used by AA for the batch actions, so my `<form ..>` tag is stripped out.

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
  index do
    selectable_column
    column :id
    ...  
    column :created_at
    column :updated_at
    actions

    panel 'Create a new Listing Featureds' do
      render partial: 'new_multi_form'
    end
  end
end
```

My panel is like this:

```
<form action="<%= create_many_backend_listing_featureds_path %>" method="post">
  <fieldset class="inputs">
    <ol>
      <li class="select input required">
        <%= label_tag :venue %>
        <%= select_tag :venue_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Venue.all, :id, :name), include_blank: true %>
      </li>

      <li class="select input required">
        <%= label_tag :area_id %>
        <%= select_tag :area_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Area.all, :id, :name), include_blank: true %>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>

  <%= submit_tag("Create") %>
</form>
```

So my question: How can I display a form in the index action of Active Admin?